# Best practice using PUT routes when updating the same table from different locations of the UI

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, backend

I understand that this question is very much opinion based however it would really help me to get some insight on how others structure their route/controller/query for their PUT requests around the same table.

My app has a `client` table. It has many columns; examples: `is_active`, `agent_id`. These columns of the same table are updated from various locations on the UI. My current approach is to write a route/controller/query for each transaction.

**Example**

**1** Updating the status for a client

PUT Route: `/api/client/[clientId]/status` receives params from UI and passes them to controller =>

Controller: `handleUpdateClientStatus` passes params to query =>

Query: `updateClientStatus` (UPDATE client SET is_active = true WHERE id = 1)

**2** Updating the agent id (FK to the agent table) for a client

PUT Route: `/api/client/[clientId]/agent` receives params from UI and passes them to controller =>

Controller: `handleUpdateClientAgentId` passes params to query =>

Query: `updateClientAgentId` (UPDATE client SET agent_id = 10 WHERE id = 1)

As you can see this seems cumbersome and there seems to be an opportunity to consolidate them but where & how? Should they all hit a generic PUT route (i.e. `/api/client) and if so should each update "instance" still have its own dedicated query that is then used by the controller based the incoming parameters?

Comment: An ORM or database-to-REST mapper might help you with this

Comment: I ended up using pgpromise to map over each update